# What is the correct way to request permissions in a Facebook iFrame application with the JS SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication, facebook-apps

I'm currently using a method like this:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'oauth', perms: "user_photos" }, post_auth_callback);
```

**Has the OAuth 2.0 upgrade changed how permissions should be requested?**  The [current Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) doesn't show a *perms* param.  It looks like it has been replaced with a *scope* param.  However, in testing, the scope param is ignored and it simply requests standard access.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FB.login() method and pass the *scope* parameter as you mentioned.  Also, make sure you set the *oauth* parameter to true in your call to FB.init() so that OAuth 2.0 is enabled.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            console.log("photo permissions granted")'
        } else {
            console.log("photo permissions denied")'
        }
    }, {
        scope : 'user_photos,friends_photos'
    });
```

Comment: Does this mean that FB.ui({method: 'oath'})... will be deprecated?

Comment: Using FB.login prompts a new browser window (popup), not a modal within the current FB chrome, so it's more for external sites, not an application/page tab within Facebook.

Comment: I don't believe there's an oAuth modal dialog in the official SDK.  For apps "within Facebook" (i.e. Canvas apps) I've seen the pop-up I explained above as well as redirection to a whole new auth page, the latter of which wouldn't really be using the JS SDK for requesting permissions.